# Pass by value instead of refernce

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
        for (var siteCounter = 0; siteCounter < audit.SessionSiteList.length; siteCounter++) {
        for (var itemCounter = 0; itemCounter < audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList.length; itemCounter++) {
            var item = audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList[itemCounter];

           item.TotalItems = audit.SessionSiteList[siteCounter].AuditItemList.length;
            item.CurrentItem = itemCounter;

            promises.push(function(){return $scope.submitaudit(item)});
        }
    }
```

When the promises are executed, they are all using the same data.  ie the last assigmnet to item gets used by all promises.  How do i pass by value?

Can i clone the data and pass that?

Comment: could you create plunker of your code

Comment: check this SO question [Closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for insight.

Comment: You need a closure. By the time the function is called the loop has completed and `item` is the last item in the loop.

Comment: Easy fix is use `forEach()` instead of `for()`